# How to upgrade SSRS report from version 2008 to version 2016?

Tags: reporting-services

I basically download a report from a report server and add it to an existing SSRS project in Visual Studio 2019 but the report doesn't upgrade to version 2016.  So, is there any way to upgrade it?  If possible, how do I upgrade it using Powershell?

Here is the schema of the SSRS report:

```xml
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

Comment: Are you not seeing the behavior documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/upgrade-reports?view=sql-server-ver16 ?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes, I saw the behavior documented in there.  After the ssrs extension finally worked, the rdl automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 automatically updates any rdl that I open.  I presume that SSRS extension has to be enabled in order for rdls to be updated.